# Box shadow cut off by jQuery Mobile's CSS

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

When opening the mobile side panel below, is there a way to prevent the box shadow on `.snap-drawer` from being cut off by jQuery Mobile's `.ui-content`?

Desired result:

[image]

```js
$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function () {
    var snapper = new Snap({
        element: $('#content')[0]
    });

    $('#open-panel').click(function () {
        snapper.open('left');
    });
});
```

```css
.ui-content, a, .snap-drawer {
    color: black;
}
.snap-content {
    background: grey;
}
.snap-drawers, .snap-drawer {
    background: green;
    /* WTF */
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
#content {
    background: #BFC7D8;
    z-index: 1;
}
.snapjs-right .snap-drawer-left {
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgithub.com/kennethkalmer/snapjs/v2.0/dist/2.0.0-rc1/snap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kennethkalmer/snapjs/v2.0/dist/2.0.0-rc1/snap.js"></script>

<div class="snap-drawers">
    <div class="snap-drawer snap-drawer-left">
        <ul>
            <li>Pretty row 1</li>
            <li>Pretty row 2</li>
            <li>Pretty row 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="content">
    <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <a id="open-panel">Open panel</a>
    </header>
</div>
```

Comment: add (margin-top: -5px;) to (.snap-drawers, .snap-drawer) css

Comment: Unfortunately the drop shadow is still cut off by `.ui-content`.

Comment: i see whats going on. if you put (inset) in box shadow you will see a 10px vertical shadow. so take out the 10px and it should be ok. eg (10px 0px 5px 0px)

Comment: Nope. Added desired result to my question. I think the only way is to toggle a shadow on `.ui-content` when clicking `Open panel`.